# How to cross-build a flutter app from Linux x64 host to Linux arm64

Tags: flutter, raspberry-pi, cross-platform, ubuntu-18.04, cross-build

I am trying to compile from linux-x64 to linux-arm64. When I type `flutter build linux --target-platform linux-arm64` I get this error: `Cross-build from Linux x64 host to Linux arm64 target is not currently supported.`

I need to know if I have to install something specific tool on my PC to do the compilation.

The `uname -a` of my pc is: `Linux jaime-Inspiron-3537 5.4.0-124-generic #140~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 5 11:43:34 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

this is my `flutter doctor -v`

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.10, on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS 5.4.0-124-generic, locale es_CU)
    • Flutter version 3.3.10 on channel stable at /home/jaime/snap/flutter/common/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 135454af32 (hace 3 semanas), 2022-12-15 07:36:55 -0800
    • Engine revision 3316dd8728
    • Dart version 2.18.6
    • DevTools version 2.15.0

[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use
      `flutter config --android-sdk` to update to that location.


[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at google-chrome

[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
    • clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1
    • cmake version 3.16.3
    • ninja version 1.10.0
    • pkg-config version 0.29.1

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[✓] VS Code (version 1.67.1)
    • VS Code at /usr/share/code
    • Flutter extension version 3.56.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • Linux (desktop) • linux  • linux-x64      • Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS 5.4.0-124-generic
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 93.0.4577.63

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Comment: I've answered on your github issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/117826#issuecomment-1370378620

Comment: If you are familiar with the snap store for Linux there is a process to automate building the same snap to multiple environments including arm. I've used it with flutter and it builds up (didn't test it though), if you're using that you may be able to extract the executable from the snap itself.

Comment: It is my snap for example https://github.com/CyBear-Jinni-user/CBJ_App_Snap/blob/main/snap/snapcraft.yaml